# How to make the controllers of an image slideshow loop?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow here on http://dlistage.businesscatalyst.com 
I would like to make the controllers to make a loop i.e display the first item on click when last item is reached.i have already done it for the images but cannot understand how to do with controllers.
Can some one help me out here please?

my html is like this

```
    <div class="controller-3">
<ul>
<li class="selected"></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>
</div>
```

and my js is like this

```
function worksCarousel(){
var totalWorks = $(".wrapper-project ul li").length;
var ampleWork = $(".project-content").width();
var ampleTotalWorks = totalWorks*ampleWork;
$('.wrapper-project ul').css('width',ampleTotalWorks)

var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
li = document.createElement('li');
while (totalWorks--) {
    fragment.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));
}

$('.controller-3 ul').append(fragment);

var index3 = 0;
var pos3 = 1;

    var images_li = $(".wrapper-project ul li").toArray(), current_img = 0;
$(images_li[current_img]).show();


$('.controller-3 ul li:first-child').addClass('selected');

$(".controller-3 ul li").click(function(){
    index3 = $(this).index();
    $(".wrapper-project").stop().animate({scrollLeft:ampleWork*index3},'slow');
     $('.controller-3 ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    //alert(ampleitem);
});
```

my css is

```
.controller-2, .controller-3 {
    float: right;
    right: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0 60px;
}
.controller-3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.controller-2 ul, .controller-3 ul {
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    right: -50%;
    position: relative;
}
.controller-2 ul li, .controller-3 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #909090;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 35px 0 0 15px;
}
.controller-3 ul li {
    border: 2px solid #909090;
}
.controller-2 ul li:hover, .controller-3 ul li:hover {
    border: 2px solid #4ad8ed;
    background: #4ad8ed;
}
.controller-2 ul li:first-child, .controller-3 ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.controller-2 ul li:last-child, .controller-3 ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
```

Comment: Nobody is going to go to your site to sift through multiple files to figure out how your slides work. Well... maybe somone will, but they should not have to and most won't. Post your code here. Questions should be self contained

Comment: i have posted the code

Comment: dots that are clickable and show how many images are there in the slideshow.

Comment: can you put this into a simple demo in jsfiddle.net with just enough css to make things change

Comment: here is the http://jsfiddle.net/ox742d99/1/FIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.controller-3 li').click(function () {
    var $btn = $(this).addClass('selected'),
        idx = $btn.index();
    $(images_li).hide().eq(idx).show();
    $btn.siblings().removeClass('selected')
});
```

Although things work when you convert `images_li` to array, you don't really need to because jQuery treats the collection as an array already.

For example try this `console.log( $(".wrapper-project ul li").length)`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ox742d99/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: How can i make the controller loop. like when i click next on the last image, the first image appears but the controller doesnot role back to the first point

Comment: To be honest the simplest is use a plugin ...there are 100's of them. But if you want a best way to tie all this together create some functions for `changecontroller(index)`, `changeImage(index)` etc and then is easier to call those from various events